# Put request is 404 not found

Tags: angular

I am in the very early stages of learning Angular, coming from React. I have created a database inside the assets folder and have successfully completed a get request using Httpclient. However this.http.put(baseUrl, ('item to be updated')) is failing, and I don't understand how angular identifies which item in the database to update. The docs say angular finds the desired item based on the second parameter's id? I would love clarification on that point (what if your database does not have id's).

Secondly, my code is not working. I think it is due to my misunderstanding of the above point but the code is below. I am receiving a 404 Not Found.

..............................................................................

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Book } from '../models/book.interface';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class BookService {
baseUrl = 'assets/db.json';
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

//this works!
getBooks(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl);
}

//this is failing!
haveRead(book: Book): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.put(this.baseUrl, book);
  }
}
```

...................................................................

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';

import { Book } from '../models/book.interface';

import { BookService } from '../services/books.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-to-read',
   templateUrl: './to-read.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./to-read.component.css']
})
export class ToReadComponent implements OnInit {
  books: Book[];

  constructor(private bookService: BookService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getBooks();
  }

  getBooks(): void {
    this.bookService.getBooks().subscribe(books => (this.books = 
   books.books));
  }


  //triggered via click handler
  onReadIt(book): void {
    book.haveRead = true;
   this.bookService.haveRead(book).subscribe();
  }
}
```

...........................................................
The database takes the shape below.

```
{
  "books": [
    {
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Harry Potter Series",
  "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
  "review": 5,
  "haveRead": true
},
.
.
.
{
  "id": 8,
  "title": "It",
  "haveRead": false
}
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: you should use `this.bookService.haveRead(book).subscribe(data => { console.log('do something'); })`

Comment: IIRC, Angular internally requires the content-type to be set on the headers for put/post to behave correctly. See [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers) for an example. Been a while since I've done it so i could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally HttpPut requests get primary key (id) from URL. I don't know how you developed your backend but let me give an example from .Net

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody] BookViewModel book){}
```

If your put function is like that you have to send Id as parameter. To do that you need to change your haveRead method on your service.
service.ts

```
haveRead(book: Book): Observable<any> {
return this.http.put(this.baseUrl + "/" + book.id, book);
}
```